# Optimal stacking of split logs

Tags: plane-geometry, packing-and-covering, circle-packing

Consider firewood logs as unit-radius cylinders of the same length.
Each log is split into $k$ pieces by equiangular sectors
meeting in the circle center:
$k=2$ leads to semicircles, $180^\circ$;
$k=3$ results in $120^\circ$ sectors, etc.

---

[image: Log5]

---

> ***Q***. What is the optimal packing of a halfplane 
>   by equiangular circular sectors, for each $k$?

I am hoping that for some $k>1$, the optimal packing is known.

---

[image: StackingLogs]

---

[image: Logs6]

---

A practical application, for small $k$ (say, at most $6$, as above [gray]), is how
to optimally stack firewood for the winter.

Comment: I'd imagine the answer for large N is probably given by alternating the orientations of the wedges to form infinite rows, then stack those on top of one another such as in the classic picture of how to estimate the area of a circle: https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/circle-area-by-sectors.html

Comment: @ARupinski: Excellent point, you are surely correct. Thanks!

Comment: At least for your first picture of packing semicircles, the density is the same as for packing circles. In 3D, there are arrangements of semispheres that are denser than close-packed sphere. They were found in this paper of Marechal and Dijkstra (look at the panel labeled IX' in Figure 7): http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.0197

Comment: @YoavKallus: Thanks for that great reference!

Comment: Good question, though the firewood application is surely fanciful because it requires unrealistic uniformity of tree widths and wood splitting . . .

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: Agree completely. But I was stacking wood, so ...

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the optimal packing of 1/6-circle wedges, but I do know that the following is the optimal packing of the shape formed by gluing two of those wedges along a full edge:

[image]

The two-wedge shape is convex and 2-fold symmetric, so its optimal packing is the optimal lattice packing, which can be solved for numerically. The density of this packing is $0.978769$. The horizontal edges have a small segment of length $0.0291219$ (if the radius is 1) hanging off and not touching the neighboring wedge. If the horizontal edges coincided fully, the density would only be $0.978263$. Compare to the density of circle packing, $0.906900$.

Comment: Beautiful! ${}{}$